# How do I generate a .NET Standard client SDK based on RestAPI in AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk, swagger, aws-api-gateway, .net-standard

Ive read within documents that AWS RestAPIs within the API Gateway service supports automating the process of generating SDK's.
I'd like to generate a **.NET Standard library** based off of an API that is contained within RestAPI (which had swagger doc used for generating docs/method)

How exactly can I auto-generate (by way of scripts) .NET standard library based on an ASP.NET Core WebAPI which is using swagger and has been placed behind RestAPI front-end?
Does AWS support .NET Standard?
What other methods of automatically generating the SDK should I consider to do the job? Any insight is appreciated, fundamentally I really liked the idea of auto generating a client sdk based on api documentation based off of swagger. And those customers I would like to do it for have heavy use of .net.

Note: Im not looking for java , javascript , android , objectivec (for iOS), swift (for iOS), and ruby. Specifically, I am looking for .net.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `NSwag.CodeGeneration.CSharp` to generate .NET clients from swagger definition. Here is my code I used for my AWS re:Invent presentation last year. https://github.com/aws-samples/cloudmosaic-dotnet/tree/reinvent-2019/Application/Clients/CloudMosaic.API.Client.Generator